# who can explain the first output?(java operator)

Tags: java, operator-keyword, ternary

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char alpha = 'A';
        int foo = 65;
        boolean trueExp = true;
        System.out.println(trueExp ? alpha : 0);
        System.out.println(trueExp ? alpha : foo);
    }
run result:A
           65
```

I can’t know the first output is A.who can explian ? thank you!

Comment: Josh Bloch and Neal Gafter explain this in Java Puzzlers.

Comment: The expression in the first `println` returns `alpha`. What else did you expect it to print if not the value of `alpha`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca presumably `65`, as it does for the second.

Answer (score 2):

From [JLS 15.25.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2):

> If one of the operands [of the conditional ? : operator] is of type `T` where `T` is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.29) of type `int` whose value is representable in type `T`, then the type of the conditional expression is `T`.

```
System.out.println(trueExp ? alpha : 0);
```

`alpha` is a `char`, `0` is an `int` with a constant expression which is representable by `char`, hence the result of the conditional expression is a `char`.

```
System.out.println(trueExp ? alpha : foo);
```

Here, `foo` is not a constant expression, so the operands will undergo binary numeric promotion to `int`, hence it prints `(int) alpha`, `65`.

If you were to declare `final int foo`, it would print `A` once again ([Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/Vvnjo0)).

Comment: Sorry ... brain failure.